# Does UITextView Implicitly Respond to Gyroscopic Rotational Events?

Tags: ios, events, rotation, uitextview, gyroscope

This application has a UITextView that is laden with a large amount of text, requiring the user to scroll the text to see all of it.

Slowly tilting the device away from the user causes the UITextView to scroll to the top of the text and freezes all scrolling functionality.

I have measured the angle at which the problem occurs and it is slightly less than 30 degrees.